# Windows Server 2008 R2 windows update stuck

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

i have a 2008 R2 Standard server (on VMware) that is stuck without being able to update.

Behavior:

Windows update fails on check for new updates error code 8000FFFF.

When rebooting, server attempts to configure updates. Reboots to login screen, then reboots a second time. At that point it attempts to configure updates (stops at 35%) and then displays the error "Error installing updates. Reverting changes." then we get to the login screen.

I Cannot run "sfc /scannow" i get the error:

```
There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete.  Restart Windows and run sfc again
```

I have run the System Update Readiness Tool from this webpage:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness
CheckSUR.log:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.22471
Package Version 26.0
2019-05-14 15:49

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 4557
 No errors detected
(w) Unable to get system disk properties    0x0000045D  IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY    Disk Cache
```

I have tried deleting files from the %windir/SoftwareDistribution/Download & DataStore.
I have tried stopping & starting (confirmed automatic delayed start) BITS, Windows Installer & Windows Update service.

I tried removing registry keys:
HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/WindowsUpdate
HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/WindowsUpdate

Nothing appears to work. I still get the 8000FFFF error and the constant attempt to install some phantom update that doesn't exist and reboots twice then reverts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

Contents of most recent cbs log:

```
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller initialization.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v6.1.7601.23505 with Core: C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23505_none_681aa442f6fed7f0\cbscore.dll
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CSI    00000001@2019/5/16:19:12:07.217 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fee6caeb5d @0x7fee6f69b6d @0x7fee6f3358f @0xff12e97c @0xff12d799 @0xff12db2f)
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    Could not load SrClient DLL from path: SrClient.dll.  Continuing without system restore points.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CSI    00000002@2019/5/16:19:12:07.217 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fee6caeb5d @0x7fee6fb6ade @0x7fee6f82984 @0x7fee6f33665 @0xff12e97c @0xff12d799)
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CSI    00000003@2019/5/16:19:12:07.217 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fee6caeb5d @0x7fefae18728 @0x7fefae18856 @0xff12e474 @0xff12d7de @0xff12db2f)
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller initialization.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    Starting the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller service starts successfully.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Initializing online with Windows opt-in: False
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Cleaning up report files older than 10 days.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Requesting upload of all unsent reports.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start upload with file pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_std.sqm, flags: 0x2 [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start standard sample upload. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Queued 0 file(s) for upload with pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_all.sqm, flags: 0x6
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    SQM: Warning: Failed to upload all unsent reports. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    No startup processing required, TrustedInstaller service was not set as autostart, or else a reboot is still pending.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Checking to ensure startup processing was not required.
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CSI    00000004 IAdvancedInstallerAwareStore_ResolvePendingTransactions (call 1) (flags = 00000004, progress = NULL, phase = 0, pdwDisposition = @0xcbfe30
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Startup processing is required unexpectedly, scheduled Trusted Installer for auto-start again. [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2019-05-16 15:12:07, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs incremented to: 1
2019-05-16 15:12:08, Info                  CBS    Startup processing thread terminated normally
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CSI    00000005 CSI Store 2829040 (0x00000000002b2af0) initialized
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Session: 30739483_1119829871 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6000.16386, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: GE, BuildComp: GE, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, state: Superseded
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, applicable state: Installed
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CSI    00000006 Transaction merge required, do-not-merge flag passed.
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CSI    00000007@2019/5/16:19:12:10.093 CSI Transaction @0x23df40 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [26]"TI5.30739483_1119829871:1/"

2019-05-16 15:12:10, Error                 CSI    00000008 (F) Primitive operations failed to complete, cannot begin another transaction[gle=0x80004005]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Error                 CSI    00000009 (F) E_UNEXPECTED #158# from Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact(...)[gle=0x8000ffff]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Error                 CSI    0000000a@2019/5/16:19:12:10.093 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\componentstore\com\store.cpp(4450): Error E_UNEXPECTED originated in function Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact expression: ((HRESULT)0x8000FFFFL)
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Error                 CSI    0000000b (F) E_UNEXPECTED #156# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction2_Analyze(Flags = 1, riid = {f4d9decb-0250-4ad4-9500-85c7f2f281ec}, ppUnk = NULL, disp = 0)[gle=0x8000ffff]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to get transaction analysis. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CSI    0000000c@2019/5/16:19:12:10.734 CSI Transaction @0x23df40 destroyed
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to load current component state [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to find or add the component family [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    ComponentAnalyzerEvaluateSelfUpdate call failed. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate self update [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate non detect parent update [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate non parent [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    failed to evaluate single applicability [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate applicability [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Info                  CBS    Failed to get applicability on updates [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:10, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, Update: ActiveX-64and32 [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:12:13, Info                  CBS    Archived backup log: C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20190516191207.cab.
2019-05-16 15:32:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30739486_527875020 initialized by client DISM Package Manager Provider.
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Session: 30739487_796970224 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6000.16386, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: GE, BuildComp: GE, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, state: Superseded
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, applicable state: Installed
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CSI    0000000d Transaction merge required, do-not-merge flag passed.
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CSI    0000000e@2019/5/16:19:40:15.778 CSI Transaction @0x23df40 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [25]"TI5.30739487_796970224:1/"

2019-05-16 15:40:15, Error                 CSI    0000000f (F) Primitive operations failed to complete, cannot begin another transaction[gle=0x80004005]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Error                 CSI    00000010 (F) E_UNEXPECTED #193# from Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact(...)[gle=0x8000ffff]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Error                 CSI    00000011@2019/5/16:19:40:15.794 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\componentstore\com\store.cpp(4450): Error E_UNEXPECTED originated in function Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact expression: ((HRESULT)0x8000FFFFL)
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Error                 CSI    00000012 (F) E_UNEXPECTED #191# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction2_Analyze(Flags = 1, riid = {f4d9decb-0250-4ad4-9500-85c7f2f281ec}, ppUnk = NULL, disp = 0)[gle=0x8000ffff]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to get transaction analysis. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CSI    00000013@2019/5/16:19:40:15.981 CSI Transaction @0x23df40 destroyed
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to load current component state [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to find or add the component family [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    ComponentAnalyzerEvaluateSelfUpdate call failed. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate self update [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate non detect parent update [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate non parent [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    failed to evaluate single applicability [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate applicability [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Info                  CBS    Failed to get applicability on updates [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:40:15, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, Update: ActiveX-64and32 [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Session: 30739489_3255608018 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6000.16386, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: GE, BuildComp: GE, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385, state: Superseded
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, applicable state: Installed
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CSI    00000014 Transaction merge required, do-not-merge flag passed.
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CSI    00000015@2019/5/16:19:58:40.635 CSI Transaction @0x23df40 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [26]"TI5.30739489_3255608018:1/"

2019-05-16 15:58:40, Error                 CSI    00000016 (F) Primitive operations failed to complete, cannot begin another transaction[gle=0x80004005]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Error                 CSI    00000017 (F) E_UNEXPECTED #228# from Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact(...)[gle=0x8000ffff]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Error                 CSI    00000018@2019/5/16:19:58:40.635 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\componentstore\com\store.cpp(4450): Error E_UNEXPECTED originated in function Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact expression: ((HRESULT)0x8000FFFFL)
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Error                 CSI    00000019 (F) E_UNEXPECTED #226# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction2_Analyze(Flags = 1, riid = {f4d9decb-0250-4ad4-9500-85c7f2f281ec}, ppUnk = NULL, disp = 0)[gle=0x8000ffff]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to get transaction analysis. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CSI    0000001a@2019/5/16:19:58:40.792 CSI Transaction @0x23df40 destroyed
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to load current component state [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to find or add the component family [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    ComponentAnalyzerEvaluateSelfUpdate call failed. [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate self update [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate non detect parent update [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate non parent [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    failed to evaluate single applicability [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to evaluate applicability [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to get applicability on updates [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
2019-05-16 15:58:40, Error                 CBS    Failed to call external evaluate applicability on package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, Update: ActiveX-64and32 [HRESULT = 0x8000ffff - Unknown Error]
```

Comment: Look in `c:\windows\logs\cbs\cbs.log` to see if there is any useful diagnostic information about the problem.

Comment: Ok i have the log file open and found some info & error entries. A bunch of googling reveals nothing. Is there something specific to look for?

Comment: If you edit the error messages into your question someone may be able to assist.

Comment: BUMP - any ideas?

Comment: Check that `WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320.cat` and `WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320.mum` (in `c:\windows\servicing\packages`) are intact by comparing them against copies on a working server.

Comment: You should probably check the .cat and .mum files for the other two packages mentioned in the log too.  Failing that, you might need to do a repair installation.  Make sure you have a good backup first, preferably a snapshot as well.

Comment: thanks Harry. if they aren't the same, should/can i copy them over from the working server?

Comment: Yes, but again, make sure you have a good backup and a snapshot in case something goes wrong.  (I've performed similar repairs on Windows 7 machines with no complications, but this sort of open-brain surgery is inherently somewhat risky.)